# Date Formula - Want a Start to End Date Formula Field

Tags: formula, formula-field, date, text

I want to have a formula field that displayes the Start Date of an event to the End Date of an event, i.e (01/01/2017 - 31/12/17) - Like this

But when I try to make it like this I can't as the dash gets read as text and it creates a syntaxt error. When I make the formula text, the field looks like this :
2017-01-01 - 2017-12-31

Is it possible to get the format I want, if so could I get help with the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure your formula return type is `text`.

You can use the `DAY()`, `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` functions wrapped in a `TEXT()` method to build the format you want, concatenating "-" and "/" characters where appropriate:

```
TEXT(DAY(Start__c)) & "/" & TEXT(MONTH(Start__c)) & "/" & TEXT(YEAR(Start__c))
& " - " &
TEXT(DAY(End__c)) & "/" & TEXT(MONTH(End__c)) & "/" & TEXT(YEAR(End__c))
```

Something like the above should work.

Comment: You're an absolute legend, mate

Comment: @Alex Happy to help! :)